# Trouble with Interfaces, Inheritance, and Polymorphism

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have come to a point in my program where my polymorphism is broken. I realize that this is in my code, and I understand why; I'm just not sure how best to resolve it.

I have three model classes which have the same interface, but very significantly different implementations. I created an interface, and then three independent classes, which also derive from a `ModelBase` class:

```
public interface IMyModel
{ ... }

public class MyModelA : ModelBase, IMyModels
{ ... }

public class MyModelB : ModelBase, IMyModels
{ ... }

public class MyModelC : ModelBase, IMyModels
{ ... }
```

So far fine and dandy.

I have a ViewModel base class, which takes a model as a constructor:

```
public abstract class MyViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModelBase(ModelBase Model)
    this.model = Model;
}
```

Now where I am caught; I want to have a concrete ViewModel class that can accept any of the three Model classes above:

```
public class MyViewModel : MyViewModelBase
{
    MyViewModel(IMyModel Model) : base (Model)   // <- Invalid Polymorphism!
    {
        // More here
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because it is possible for an implementation of IMyModel to not be based on ModelBase.  The argument cannot be safely passed to the base constructor.

I can see one solution being to create an abstract base class derived from ModelBase for these models with exception-throwing content, and using that as the type in my ViewModel.  I had started with a base class, but found that almost every part had some difference!  However, that seems like a lot of work.  Also, it won't ensure that derived classes implement everything (like an interface does).  Finally, it seems to devalue the interface concept (indeed, I wouldn't need one anymore).

I don't see any way of marking the interface as saying that derived classes must have a specific base class.  It would be nice if I could do this, but it's not allowed:

```
public interface IMyModel : MyModelBase
{ ... }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Clarification:**

I probably oversimplified the names here.  I have other Models and ViewModels using the base classes, but not implementing the interface.

```
public class MyOtherModel : ModelBase  // But not IMyModel!
{ ... }

public class MyOtherViewModel : MyViewModelBase
{
    MyOtherViewModel(MyOtherModel Model) : base(Model)  // This works
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why not have the MyViewModelBase constructor take IMyModels rather than ModelBase?

Comment: Can MyViewModelBase constructor not just accept IMyModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your base class implement the interface, then inherit your implementation classes from the base class, marking the base class and methods as abstract (MustInherit/MustOverride in VB parlance).  This would give you your polymorphism and guarantee the interface.

Comment: Aha!!!  I did not realize you could mark properties and methods as `abstract` as well as classes!  The compiler does give an error if the derived class is missing an implementation.  I can actually get rid of the interface declaration, as the abstract members provide an equivalent purpose now.  Thank you!

Comment: Im glad you found it helpful.

Comment: "marking the base class and interface methods as abstract" FYI, you can't mark interface methods as abstract.

Comment: Thank you @Mud.  Edited as per your comment.

Comment: @mbmcavoy. No, don't get rid of the interface! Make yourself not dependent on the base class but on the interface. It gives you  a higher abstraction level and allows you to use different base classes or to implement a model not deriving from the base class at all, if no base class fits really well.

Answer (score 2):

you could use generic constraints:

```
public class MyViewModel<T> : MyViewModelBase where T : IMyModel , ModelBase
{
    MyViewModel(T model) : base (model)   // T inherits ModelBase and implements IMyModel , so it is legal
    {
        // More here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer.  I had been thinking of some sort of way to say that the object being passed had to be both IMyModel and ModelBase.  In other circumstances, this could be the right answer.  However, the <T> would need to be known at compile time, right?  Unfortunately, I will be populating the MyViewModels from a collection of IMyModels, and any/all of the concrete types will be present.

Comment: @mbmcavoy : No. Unlike c++ templates .Net generics are evaluated at runtime. This is designed so you can use reflection, or use generic libraries externally.

Answer (score 1):

Often (not always) when you find yourself building an Abstract Base Class it means you are trying to share both an interface and some common logic. Perhaps you can split these two things?

Move the common interface into IMyModels, and extract the common functionality into a separate class. Then include an instance of that helper class in each model. Essentially use composition to share functionality instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Make ModelBase implement IMyModel. If ModelBase does not implement all methods of the interface, implement them as abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding

- Models are stupid Data containers
- Interfaces describe behaviour and Functionality, not data.

So why bother putting interfaces on the models at all?

@Yochai : Good point, using Generics - saves code, but you must first declare base classes (only one per class, there's no mixed inheritance in C#), then any amount of interfaces, thus your code should be:

```
public class MyViewModel<T> : MyViewModelBase where T : ModelBase, IMyModel
```

Comment: I disagree that models should be simple data containers without any functionality or interfaces.  At a minimum, INotifyPropertyChanged (or a similar notification scheme) is necessary if more than one ViewModel is looking at the same model.  (The ModelBase class mentioned above implements it.) Otherwise changes in one place will not be reflected in the other.  The .NET list and collections classes are very useful in models, and clearly have complex functionality.  Finally, methods needed to maintain integrity of the model should be put in the model instead of perhaps multiple ViewModels.